# jQuery drag and drop getting stuck while dragging over Tinymce Editor

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

When I quickly moving draggable item over tinymce editor it's getting stuck. Otherwise it works.

Please share if you have solution to fix this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(".item").draggable({ 
      iframeFix:true
 });
```